# Error in Data Conversion date to int but all seem matched up

Tags: sql, vb.net, adodb

Implicit conversion from data type datetime to tinyint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. is tjhe error I am getting along with Varchar to date, I know the normal problem with this but I cant seem to figure this one out.

I have the code calling the SP below:

```
  Public Function SavePropertyExpiries() As Boolean
    '** Save Current Personal Data Record

    ' Error Checking
    'On Error GoTo Err_SaveProperty

    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset



    ' Check For Open Connection
    If uDBase Is Nothing Then
        OpenConnection()
        bConnection = True
    End If

    ' Run Stored Procedure - Save PropertyExpiries Record
    uCommand = New ADODB.Command
    With uCommand
        .ActiveConnection = uDBase
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 0

        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text)))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@HMOLicenced", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkHMOLicenced.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@HMOExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpHMOExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@HMOLicenseRef", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60, txtHMOLicenseRef.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@HMONotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtHMONotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@GasSafetyCheck", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkGasSafetyCheck.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@GasSafetyExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpGasSafetyExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@GasSafetyNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtGasSafetyNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PAT", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkPAT.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PATExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpPATExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PATNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtPATNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EICR", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkEICR.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EICRExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpEIRCExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EICRNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtEIRCNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@FireSafety", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkFireSafety.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@FiresafetyExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpFiresafetyExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@FireSafetyNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtFiresafetyNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EPC", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkEPC.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EPCExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpEPCExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EPCRating", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , cmbEPCRating.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@EPCNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtEPCNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@Insurance", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkInsurance.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@InsurenceExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpInsurenceExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@InsurenceNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtInsurenceNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyInspection", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkPropertyInspection.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyInspectionDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpPropertyInspectionDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyInspectionInMonths", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , nudPropertyInspectionInMonths.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyInspectionNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtPropertyInspectionNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@LandLordRegistration", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkLandLordRegistration.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpLandLordRegistrationExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@LandlordRegistrationNo", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtLandlordRegistrationNo.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@LandlordRegistrationNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtLandlordRegistrationNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@NextRentReview", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkNextRentReview.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@NextRentReviewExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpNextRentReviewExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@NextRentreviewNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtNextRentreviewNotes.Text))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@ManagementFeeReview", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , -chkManagementFeeReview.Checked))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@ManagementExpiryDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , dtpManagementExpiryDate.Value))
        uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@ManagementfeeReviewNotes", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 100, txtManagementfeeReviewNotes.Text))

        .CommandText = "PropertyExpiries_SaveRecord"

        .Execute()
    End With

    ' Close Connection
    uRecSnap = Nothing
    uCommand = Nothing
    If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
    SavePropertyExpiries = True

Err_SaveProperty:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sErrDescription = Err.Description
        WriteAuditLogRecord("clsPropertyExpiries", "SaveExpiries", "Error", sErrDescription)
        SavePropertyExpiries = False
    End If

 End Function
```

Herer is the SP itselft:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PropertyExpiries_SaveRecord] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @PropertyID as int, @HMOLicenced as tinyint, @HMOExpiryDate as date, @HMOLicenseRef as varchar(60), @HMONotes as varchar(60), 
    @GasSafetyCheck as tinyint, @GasSafetyExpiryDate as date, @GasSafetyNotes as varchar(100), @PAT as tinyint, 
    @PATExpiryDate as date, @PATNotes as varchar(60), @EICR as tinyint, @EICRExpiryDate as date, @EICRNotes as varchar(60), 
    @FireSafety as tinyint, @FiresafetyExpiryDate as date, @FireSafetyNotes as varchar(60), @EPC as tinyint, 
    @EPCExpiryDate as date, @EPCRating tinyint, @EPCNotes as varchar(60), @Insurance as tinyint, @InsurenceExpiryDate as date, @InsurenceNotes as varchar(60),
    @LandlordRegistrationNo as varchar(60),@PropertyInspection as tinyint, @PropertyInspectionDate as date,
    @PropertyInspectionInMonths as tinyint, @PropertyInspectionNotes as varchar(60), @LandLordRegistration as tinyint,
    @LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate as date, @LandlordRegistrationNotes as varchar(60), @NextRentReview as tinyint, @NextRentReviewExpiryDate as date, 
    @NextRentreviewNotes as varchar(60), @ManagementFeeReview as tinyint, @ManagementExpiryDate as date, @ManagementfeeReviewNotes as varchar(60)

AS

If  (SELECT ISNULL(PropertyID , 0 ) FROM  PropertyExpiries WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID) = 0


BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PropertyExpiries (PropertyID, HMOLicenced, HMOExpiryDate, HMOLicenseRef, HMONotes, GasSafetyCheck, GasSafetyExpiryDate, GasSafetyNotes, PAT, PATExpiryDate, PATNotes, EICR, EICRExpiryDate, EICRNotes, FireSafety, FiresafetyExpiryDate, FireSafetyNotes, EPC, EPCExpiryDate, EPCRating, EPCNotes, Insurance, InsurenceExpiryDate, InsurenceNotes, PropertyInspection, PropertyInspectionDate, PropertyInspectionInMonths, PropertyInspectionNotes, LandLordRegistration, LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate, LandlordRegistrationNo, LandlordRegistrationNotes, NextRentReview, NextRentReviewExpiryDate, NextRentreviewNotes, ManagementFeeReview, ManagementExpiryDate, ManagementfeeReviewNotes)
        VALUES ( @PropertyID, @HMOLicenced, @HMOExpiryDate, @HMOLicenseRef, @HMONotes, @GasSafetyCheck, @GasSafetyExpiryDate, @GasSafetyNotes, @PAT, @PATExpiryDate, @PATNotes, @EICR, @EICRExpiryDate, @EICRNotes, @FireSafety, @FiresafetyExpiryDate, @FireSafetyNotes,  @EPC, @EPCExpiryDate, @EPCRating, @EPCNotes, @Insurance, @InsurenceExpiryDate, @InsurenceNotes, @PropertyInspection, @PropertyInspectionDate,  @PropertyInspectionInMonths, @PropertyInspectionNotes, @LandLordRegistration, @LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate, @LandlordRegistrationNo, @LandlordRegistrationNotes, @NextRentReview, @NextRentReviewExpiryDate, @NextRentreviewNotes, @ManagementFeeReview, @ManagementExpiryDate, @ManagementfeeReviewNotes)
    END

BEGIN
    UPDATE PropertyExpiries SET 

    PropertyID = @PropertyID,
    HMOLicenced = @HMOLicenced,
    HMOExpiryDate = @HMOExpiryDate,
    HMOLicenseRef = @HMOLicenseRef,
    HMONotes = @HMONotes,
    GasSafetyCheck = @GasSafetyCheck,
    GasSafetyExpiryDate = @GasSafetyExpiryDate,
    GasSafetyNotes = @GasSafetyNotes,
    PAT = @PAT,
    PATExpiryDate = @PATExpiryDate,
    PATNotes = @PATNotes,
    EICR = @EICR,
    EICRExpiryDate = @EICRExpiryDate,
    EICRNotes = @EICRNotes,
    FireSafety = @FireSafety,
    FiresafetyExpiryDate = @FiresafetyExpiryDate,
    FireSafetyNotes = @FireSafetyNotes,
    EPC = @EPC,
    EPCExpiryDate = @EPCExpiryDate,
    EPCRating = @EPCRating,
    EPCNotes = @EPCNotes,
    Insurance = @Insurance,
    InsurenceExpiryDate = @InsurenceExpiryDate,
    InsurenceNotes = @InsurenceNotes,
    PropertyInspection = @PropertyInspection,
    PropertyInspectionDate = @PropertyInspectionDate,
    PropertyInspectionInMonths = @PropertyInspectionInMonths,
    PropertyInspectionNotes = @PropertyInspectionNotes,
    LandLordRegistration = @LandLordRegistration,
    LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate = @LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate,
    LandlordRegistrationNo = @LandlordRegistrationNo,
    LandlordRegistrationNotes = @LandlordRegistrationNotes,
    NextRentReview = @NextRentReview,
    NextRentReviewExpiryDate = @NextRentReviewExpiryDate,
    NextRentreviewNotes = @NextRentreviewNotes,
    ManagementFeeReview = @ManagementFeeReview,
    ManagementExpiryDate = @ManagementExpiryDate,
    ManagementfeeReviewNotes = @ManagementfeeReviewNotes



        WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID 
END
```

Table:

```
    USE [BMSSouthSide]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PropertyExpiries]    Script Date: 29/01/2015 11:04:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PropertyExpiries](
    [PropertyID] [int] NULL,
    [HMOLicenced] [tinyint] NULL,
    [HMOExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [HMOLicenseRef] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [HMONotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [GasSafetyCheck] [tinyint] NULL,
    [GasSafetyExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [GasSafetyNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PAT] [tinyint] NULL,
    [PATExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [PATNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EICR] [tinyint] NULL,
    [EICRExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [EICRNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FireSafety] [tinyint] NULL,
    [FiresafetyExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [FireSafetyNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EPC] [tinyint] NULL,
    [EPCExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [EPCRating] [tinyint] NULL,
    [EPCNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Insurance] [tinyint] NULL,
    [InsurenceExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [InsurenceNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PropertyInspection] [tinyint] NULL,
    [PropertyInspectionDate] [date] NULL,
    [PropertyInspectionInMonths] [tinyint] NULL,
    [PropertyInspectionNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LandLordRegistration] [tinyint] NULL,
    [LandLordRegistrationExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [LandlordRegistrationNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LandlordRegistrationNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [NextRentReview] [tinyint] NULL,
    [NextRentReviewExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [NextRentreviewNotes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ManagementFeeReview] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ManagementExpiryDate] [date] NULL,
    [ManagementfeeReviewNotes] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it looks lined up to me too. You haven't posted the schema for the PropertyExpiries table but I assume you have checked that one of the date columns isn't defined as a tinyint?

In cases like this I use SQL Server Profiler to capture *exactly* what the client is executing against SQL Server then try running the query inside SSMS - at the very least you should get a better idea of which point in the execution the mismatch is occuring.

Comment: my table is up now @RhysJones sorry forgot about that